# React native FlatList default data name

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have list of data that want to show using [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/flatlist.html) , as all examples I have seen like this from [reactnativeexpress.com](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/flatlist) :

```
const sections = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Basic Components',
    data: [
      {id: 0, text: 'View'},
      {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
      {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'List Components',
    data: [
      {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
      {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
    ]
  }
]
```

Items should be a list named `data` but if I get data from an API that items list is not named `data`, and it will not show the content. ( I tested with this example and if change `data` to `dat` items will not shown) , is there any way to change `data` default name or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that item list should be named `data` so I added a pointer to my list :

```
content.payload.APIList.map((eachcat) => eachcat.data = eachcat.APISubList)
```